# GitLab installation - license

Tags: git, gitlab

We are migrating from SVN to GIT and I am looking for free software to set up GIT on our private machine in a company. We don't want to use any GIT hosted on clouds or outside servers. I found that GitLab should be fine, but I have a question about license.
Is GitLab hosted on private server free? Can I freely use Omnibus package installation in community edition from https://about.gitlab.com/installation/ ?

Comment: go for gogs instead.https://gogs.io/

Comment: Thanks, at first glance looks good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can do whatever you like with the omnibus community edition of GitLab hosted privately. See here for the [community licence](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/LICENSE) and here for the [omnibus licence](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/LICENSE).

The community licence is free for everything but the omnibus apache 2.0 licencing requires you to include the copyright/licence yourself and state any changes.